# Setting <li> background to full width + centering vertical height, possible?

Tags: html, css

to cut to the chase:

I have a **vertical** menu-bar and I want to have an `<li>` element with full background color + vertical align.
I've seen here someone recommending adding the `vertical-align: middle;` won't suffice and I would need to add a `display: table-cell;` but that doesn't really help vertical menus.

**HTML**

```
<div class="sidebar">
  <img src="img/Logo.png">
<ul>
  <li><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-home" style="color: white;"></span><a href="#">Home</a></li>
</ul>
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
.sidebar{
  width:150px;
  background-color: #0e1a35;
  height: 100%;
}
.sidebar > img:nth-child(1){
  width: 70%;
  display:block;
  margin:auto;
  padding: 5px  ;

}

.sidebar > ul {
  list-style: none;
  padding:0;
  margin:0;
  width: 100%;
}

.sidebar > ul > li{
  text-decoration: none;
  background-color: #42105d;
  height:50px;
  vertical-align: middle;
  float: none;
  width: 100%;


  text-align: left;
  border-left: #5584ff 4px solid;
}
.sidebar > ul > li > a{
  color: white;
  text-decoration: none;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  position: relative;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  display: inline-block;

}
.sidebar .glyphicon{
  margin-left: 0px;
  margin-right: 10px;
}
```

So my question is how to have the `<li>` vertical aligned with a background color covering the `<li>` **without changing the padding/margin of the `<li>`**

Comment: your CSS is fuzzy and cut-out.  Can you do a better code sample that respects a [mcve]? I mean... think about it: you create some small CSS + HTML and you get an answer in no-time. You create some partial CSS and you can wait and wait...

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan , Done.

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan - Do you know HTML/CSS? or just stackoverflow standards? :D Thanks mate.

Comment: hahahaha fair comment :D you made my day! (Sorry I was away let me see what you got)

Comment: I re-edited, just paste in fiddle and see what you can do with this. I want the <li> texts to be vertically centered without touching padding/margin.

Comment: So wait in jsfiddle I have this https://jsfiddle.net/RokoCB/e1koayn0/ I'm still missing to understand the desired output...

Comment: the <li>, <a>  text - I need it vertically aligned to center.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- HTML: Wrap icon and all inside the `A` element
- Don't style the `LI`
- Focus styling the `A`nchor element instead
- For vertical alignment you can use `line-height` to match the actual
  `height`

```css
@import url("//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/css/bootstrap-glyphicons.css");

*{box-sizing: border-box;}
body{margin:0;}

.sidebar{
  width:150px;
}
.sidebar ul{
  margin:0;
  padding:0;
}
.sidebar a{
  text-decoration:none;
  display:block;
  background: #42105d;
  color:#fff;
  border-left: #5584ff 4px solid;
  height:50px;
  line-height:50px;
  padding: 0 8px;
}
```

```html
<div class="sidebar">
  <ul>
    <li>
      <a href="#"> <!-- WRAP ALL INSIDE THE ANCHOR! -->
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-home" style="color: white;"></span> Home
      </a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Here's an example **without** using `line-height` and `height` but instead playing with `A`'s padding:

```css
@import url("//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/css/bootstrap-glyphicons.css");

*{box-sizing: border-box;}
body{margin:0;}

.sidebar ul{
  width:150px;
  margin:0;
  padding:0;
}
.sidebar a{
  text-decoration:none;
  display:block;
  background: #42105d;
  color:#fff;
  border-left: #5584ff 4px solid;
  padding: 16px 8px;
}
```

```html
<div class="sidebar">
  <ul>
    <li>
      <a href="#">
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-home" style="color: white;"></span> Home
      </a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="#">
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-user" style="color: white;"></span> About
      </a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="#">
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-envelope" style="color: white;"></span> Contact
      </a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Yes, I know line height, I thought there was another auto way to get vertical-align to take the height of the element into consideration. Thanks Rocco.